# Riemannian covering map of $\mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, covering-spaces, projective-space

We know that there is a Riemannian covering map $p:S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$  and I'm working with some foliation problem, which ended up in  trying to find a Riemannian covering map of $\mathbb{C}P^n$, but I don't know any Riemannian cover of this space.

I would like to find some references to this subject, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of Riemannian covering?

Comment: A Riemannian covering is a smooth covering that is also a local Riemannian isometry

Comment: I don't know if it can help you : $\mathbb{CP}^{n} = \displaystyle \cup_{j = 0}^{n} E_{j}$ where $E_{j}$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. This biholomorphism can be used to define a local Riemannian isometry?If this comment is irrelevant, please tell me so that I can delete it. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if this is useful, but it may be! Can you tell me any reference where I can find this construction?

Comment: http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/diff_geom/*diff_geometry(II)/complex_projective_space/compelx_proj_1.pdf

Comment: It is worth noting that although there is no interesting Riemannian covering map (see the accepted answer), there is a natural Riemannian submersion $S^{2n+1} \to \Bbb CP^n$, the so-called Hopf fibration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is simply connected, it has no nontrivial covers (that is, any covering space if $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is just a disjoint union of copies of $\mathbb{C}P^n$).  In general, if $X$ is a connected space that is reasonably nice (e.g., a manifold), then connected covering spaces of $X$ are classified by subgroups of the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$.  You can find details in any introductory text on algebraic topology.

(Note that if $X$ has some additional local structure, such as that of a Riemannian manifold, then for any covering space $p:Y\to X$ you can uniquely lift that local structure to $Y$ such that $p$ preserves it, since $p$ is locally a homeomorphism.  So, for instance, classifying Riemannian covering spaces of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is the same as just classifying ordinary topological covering spaces of $\mathbb{C}P^n$.)